# How to say "as you wish" in Chinese

Tags: translation, idioms

I want to know what to say in the following scenario: I am pushing someone for his own good, and he is not doing what I want, so I would then say to him "Okay, as you wish." How can I express this in Chinese?

---

**Update:** 如你所愿（rúnǐsuǒyuàn）from Google Translate is not understood as having the same meaning by Chinese speakers.

Comment: jukuu has 100 examples for "as you wish" covering any possible situation (apparent from the rest of the sentence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that “随你便” may suit your needs.  This phrase can be translated as "as you wish" or "suit yourself" or even "whatever."

Comment: At least equally (probably more?) common would be **随便你** _suíbiàn nî_, rather than 随你（的）便 _suí nî(de) biàn_. If you wish to sound a bit annoyedly resigned, you can add **吧** _ba_ at the end of the sentence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

In your context, you can say 悉听尊便。

You may also use 任 as the first character.

You may also use 随 as the second character.

You may also use 君 as the third character, though that is rarely used in speech.

You may also use 意 as the fourth character.

Which of these characters you use, 悉随君意。 :-)

Answer (score 1):

If congratulatory words, you can say '祝你心想事成'.
If for greetings, ..., in fact, there's no such greetings exactly, maybe '随你便' is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I also heard people just saying 好吧,随你! (without便) in that kind of situation. Colloquial, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I am a Chinese native. in your situation, you can say(either is okay):
1) 好了,随你便了
2) 好吧,你爱咋滴咋滴(or 你爱怎么样就怎么样, more colloquially used and shows more energy than above)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best answer is -- OK， ill do what you say. 
-好的，就照你说的做。
Hǎo de, jiù zhào nǐ shuō de zuò
-好的，按你说的做。
Hǎo de, àn nǐ shuō de zuò.
-好的，听你的。
Hǎo de, tīng nǐ de.
-好的，随你。
Hǎo de, suí nǐ.